# Location enabled is always false in salesforce android SDK

Tags: mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android

There is this variable I want to modify from my android code by default its false, when I print stacktrace of getSdkState() this is what I get in the logs.

**"location_Enabled":false**

MY GPS location is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation regarding [Geofence Messaging](https://bit.ly/3rBfTOS).  You must enable the feature during SDK initialization which also requires that you add some manifest entries, a location dependency and ask the user for their permission.

Comment: Hi @Bill Thanks for the response.
I've added .setGeofencingEnabled(true) 
when I init my SDK by doing this it only changes the value of
"LocationManager":{"geofencingEnabled":true,"proximityEnabled":false,"apiCode":0,"apiMessage":"SUCCESS","locationRequests":0,"locationsReceived":0,"geofenceEvents":0} 
But I need to change the value of location_Enabled which is part of RegistrationManager  I am still getting RegistrationManager":{"current_registration":{"deviceID":"B392C2E3038E8CC","device_Token":"sdfsdf","sdk_Version":"7.2.0","app_Version":"1" : 2115","dST":false,"location_Enabled":false

Comment: Did you add the manifest entries?
Did you ask for the user's permission to use location?
Do you have the Firebase Location dependency added to your application?

All of those things must be completed in order to enable geofence messaging within your application.  There is no magic here.  Follow the documentation linked in this answer.

Comment: geofence and location goes hand to hand but my requirement is not to enable geofence, my requirement is to send the location true/false to the marketing cloud if user has its location enabled/disable and this information I can get from the android APIs in my app location data is going to 3rd party API so no issue with permissions. My question is for marketing cloud sdk changing this location_Enabled parameter do I need to really implement geofencing ? Thanks

Comment: If you want to change that parameter, then yes, you need to implement geofence messaging.  If you simply want to know the state of something then create a custom attribute in the Marketing Cloud and set the value from within the SDK.  See https://bit.ly/3qJ9GiG